# Can I use Powershell script on Win8 machine to copy files from xxx.sharepoint.com?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-office-365

I am confused if my request is possible.
The company I work for uses Office 365 and they gave us Sharepoint.  We access SP by going to xxx.sharepoint.com on the Internet.
I am thinking of writing a Powershell script that runs on my Windows 8 machine to upload files from a network drive in the office WAN to xxx.sharepoint.com.  I have write permission to some document libraries in xxx.sharepoint.com and I am a site administrator of xxx.sharepoint.com but **not** the global administrator.

Does it mean that my Powershell script will never work?

Comment: A XXX-rated SharePoint site?  Nice... sounds like a cool way to increase employee morale.  I'll have to suggest this to my boss at our next staff meeting.

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to be the global admin for an entire SharePoint Online deployment to upload files to a single library, so no, it can certainly be done

Comment: Thanks Mathias.
When I ran "Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell;", I kept getting "No snap-ins have been registered for Windows PowerShell version 4" and I have nothing under "get-PSSnapIn -registered"
That makes me think that I have to execute the PS script on a Sharepoint server.
Do you know if I can get the Snapin for my Windows 8 machine?

Comment: You don't need the snap-in, use the SharePoint client API, [as shown in this example](http://blog.vgrem.com/2014/07/29/uploading-files-into-office-365-via-powershell/)

Comment: Thanks Mathias again.  You have shown me in the right direction.  I have been able to copy some snippets from the Internet to upload files from a local directory.  
One thing though: when I upload the file to Sharepoint, I want the local file last modified date to be copied to Sharepoint directory as well.  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: It's the same issue as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058369/last-modified-property-when-streaming-a-file-to-an-external-sharepoint) - since the file in SP is a new file with the exact same contents, the timestamp is different. You want to emulate the same behavior as in the linked answer: Retrieve the item after upload, modify the metadata and then update/overwrite